# Error message in jags - Attempt to redefine node

Tags: jags

I'm trying to run a non-homogeneous Markov Chain in JAGS. I have something wrong because when I run my code I get the following error:

RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 5.
Attempt to redefine node y[2,2,1]

I'd appreciate any help.

```
model
{ 
for (t in 2:T){
for (m in 1:M){
y[t,x[t-1,m],m]~dcat(p[t,m,x[t-1,m],1:J])
#Individual transition data where m represents individual index
y[t,x[t-1,m],m]<-x[t,m]
}}

#hyper parameter
for (t in 2:T){
for (m in 1:M){
for (i in 1:I){
for (j in 1:J){
p[t,m,i,j]<-phi[t,m,i,j]/sum(phi[t,m,i,1:J])
}}}}

for (t in 2:T){
for (m in 1:M){
for (i in 1:I){
for (j in 1:J){
log(phi[t,m,i,j])<-gamma1[t,j]+gamma2[t,i,j]+beta[i,j]*age[t,m]
}}}}

#define the component with multivariate normal
for (t in 2:T){
gamma1[t,1:J]~dmnorm(gamma1[t-1,1:J],W1[1:J,1:J])
}
gamma1[1,1:J]~dmnorm(mu.gamma1[1:J],W1[1:J,1:J])

for (t in 2:T){
for (i in 1:I){
gamma2[t,i,1:J]~dmnorm(gamma2[t-1,i,1:J],W2[1:J,1:J])
}}
for (i in 1:I){
gamma2[1,i,1:J]~dmnorm(mu.gamma2[i,1:J],W2[1:J,1:J])
}
for (i in 1:I){
beta[i,1:J]~dmnorm(mu.beta[i,1:J],W.beta[1:J,1:J])
}

W1[1:J,1:J]~dwish(R[1:J,1:J],5)
W2[1:J,1:J]~dwish(R[1:J,1:J],5)
W.beta[1:J,1:J]~dwish(R[1:J,1:J],5)

#loglikelihood
for (t in 2:T){
for (m in 1:M){
llike[t,m]<-log(p[t,m,x[t-1,m],x[t,m]])
}}
for (t in 2:T){
sumllike.t[t]<-sum(llike[t,1:M])
}
#Deviance
D<--2*sum(sumllike.t[2:T])
}
```

Comment: What line is line 5?

Comment: @AbsoluteSpace line 5 is the following:   y[t,x[t-1,m],m]~dcat(p[t,m,x[t-1,m],1:J])

Comment: What are the values in the `x` object? If there are repeat values you could possibly get this error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem.